# Flash embed source redirect does not handle query parameters added by redirect (IE & Chrome only)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, redirect, parameters

I have a problem with a redirected source of a swf file in chrome and IE only. This is needed for a theme management system that redirects the virtual theme swf (mod-rewrite) to the original swf with additional color parameters. The user can select the color with a combobox, for example: default, black, gold, orange etc.

For example:

```
User select 'black' in combobox
virtual source: http://myserver/mytheme/black.swf
redirects to: http://myserver/mytheme/default.swf?color1=0000&color2=&FFFFFF& ......
```

The virtual source is linked to a theme manager called theme.php. This theme manager applies the correct parameters for the default.swf file (from a database) and redirects it to the default.swf file with applied parameters.

Finally, the swf 'default.swf' applies the color query parameters and change some objects to the colors specified.

This is working OK in Firefox and Opera. But in Chrome and IE the query parameters are lost, the swf shows the default colors. I think that this is because the src parameter is still pointing to the virtual file (the one without query parameters)?

Can somebody explain to me what is going on? or better, does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, no answer to this question.

Solved this differently. Instead of redirect the (for example) black.swf to the default.swf with applied parameters, i change the code to first request the server for the color parameters for the color black. Then i apply the default.swf with the received parameters directly to the object and this working OK.

Not a real solution but a workaround. Still not clear why redirection of a file in an object tag/embed tag is not working.